# iOS 5 Split View Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I am familiar with the split view controller for the iPad but I was wondering if there was a way to have two levels of that.  What I want is a tab bar where I pick a category.  What is then shown on the left side of the split view is a sub-category and then when I select that I want to display the items in a table view that fit those two.  Once a user selects an item then the right side of the split view will show the details about that item.

Can this be done?  If so, an example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely drill down through table view controllers on the left side of a split view.  The master view controller is usually wrapped by a navigation controller so you can simply push new table views until you get to the lowest-level category, then have it update the detail.